# Base path for src files in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

How can I set the default path and don't write every time `src/js/vendor/`? Is it possible?

Note: I can't take all the files like `src/js/vendor/**.js`

```
gulp.task('js-vendor', function() {
    return gulp.src([
      'src/js/vendor/some_one.js',
      'src/js/vendor/some_two.js',
      'src/js/vendor/some_three.js'
    ])
      .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to make a suitable matching pattern then the paths are just an array of strings so you can easily build them. You could even use something like:

```
  gulp.task('js-vendor', function() {
     return gulp.src([
       'some_one.js',
       'some_two.js',
       'some_three.js'
      ].map( file => 'src/js/vendor/' + file ))
  .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
 })
```